# Duvida sobre xamarin-forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Boa noite,

Estou iniciando um projeto de TCC com desenvolvimento para plataforma mobile e meu grupo estamos desenvolvendo utilizando a plataforma Xamarin forms, minha duvida é a respeito da criação do projeto, pois estamos tentando fazer uma comunicação via web-service e só estamos conseguindo adicionar as bibliotecas necessárias o Microsoft.Net.HTTP e a Newtonsoft utilizando o projeto cross-plataform que não conta com a opção de drag and drop para a criação das views, existe alguma forma de utilizar esse drag and drop para desenvolver as views com o cross plataform ou é apenas utilizando arquivos XML mesmo ?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível construir as views com drag-and-drop de componentes pois não há um editor de layout para isso.

O método de construir as views é realmente através do XAML (e é muito melhor do que parece em um primeiro contato).

Para começar, você pode utilizar ferramentas de *pré-visualização instantânea de XAML* como o [Forms Previewer](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer?tabs=vswin) ou o [Gorilla Player](https://grialkit.com/gorilla-player/) (Este segundo é o mais popular).

[Neste artigo, Adam Padley dá umas dicas de como o Gorilla Player funciona](http://xamarinhelp.com/visual-designer-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: Ah, ok, obrigado pela informação